# Flattening a dictionary representing a graph into a dictionary of lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary, graph, list-comprehension

I have a dictionary that represents a graph that looks like so:

```
{
   '1': ['2', '3', '4'],
   '2': ['5', '6', '7'],
   '3': ['8', '9', '10'],
}
```

I'd like to "flatten" it such that I end up with something like:

```
{
 '1': {
     '2': ['5', '6', '7'], 
     '3': ['8', '9', '10'],
     '4': []  # or None, doesn't matter
 }
}
```

However, I'm trying to account for multiple levels of nesting, so if the original graph looked like:

```
{
   '1': ['2', '3', '4'],
   '2': ['5', '6', '7'],
   '3': ['8', '9', '10'],
   '7': ['11', '12']
}
```

The final structure would look something like:

```
{
 '1': {
     '2': ['5', '6', {'7': ['11', '12']}], 
     '3': ['8', '9', '10'],
     '4': []  # or None, does not matter
 }
}
```

The easiest way I can think of doing this is brute forcing it and iterating over the graph several times and "move" the keys around, but I was hoping for a more efficient, cleaner solution.

Comment: what research have you done? see [ask].

Comment: The flattened one is less flat than the original...

Comment: What I ended up doing was using a dictionary to keep track of "root" ids and one to map parent to child relationships  and then another to child to parent relationships, and would essentially for a given id backtrack up until I found the corresponding list / dictionary to index into. Probably not a great way of explaining it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not produce the output which is formatted 'exactly' as you asked for, but hopefully it is close enough to be usable.

```
def flatten_dict(in_dict):
    in_dict_keys = in_dict.keys()
    in_dict_values = in_dict.values()
    in_dict_values_list = []
    for value1 in in_dict_values:
        for value2 in value1:
            in_dict_values_list.append(value2)
    flattenned_dict = in_dict.copy()

    "create new dict with 'substtitutions'"
    for key in in_dict_keys:
        for i, value in enumerate(in_dict[key]):
            if value in in_dict_keys:
                flattenned_dict[key][i] = {value:in_dict[value]}
    "clean up new dict"
    for value in in_dict_values_list:
        if value in flattenned_dict:
            del flattenned_dict[value]

    return flattenned_dict

if __name__ == "__main__":
    input1 = {'1': ['2', '3', '4'],'2': ['5', '6', '7'],'3': ['8', '9', '10'],}
    input2 = {'1': ['2', '3', '4'],'2': ['5', '6', '7'],'3': ['8', '9', '10'],'7': ['11', '12']}
    flattenned_dict = flatten_dict(input2)
    print(flattenned_dict)
```